# Hooking IDbInterceptor to EntityFramework DbContext only once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6, interceptor

The [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx) interface is not very well documented. And I've only found a few scarce tutorials on it:

- http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606%28v=vs.113%29.aspx
- https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_command_interception.htm
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

And a few SO questions:

- [Entity Framework 6 - Timing queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27196944/1380710)
- [Getting DbContext from implementation of IDbCommandInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28995593/1380710)

---

These are the suggestions on hooking I've found:

**1** - The static `DbInterception` class:

```
DbInterception.Add(new MyCommandInterceptor());
```

**2** - Doing the above suggestion in a `DbConfiguration` class

```
public class MyDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration {
    public MyDBConfiguration() {
        DbInterception.Add(new MyCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

**3** - Using the config file:

```
<entityFramework>
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor type="EFInterceptDemo.MyCommandInterceptor, EFInterceptDemo"/>
  </interceptors>
</entityFramework>
```

---

Although I couldn't figure out how to hook the `DbConfiguration` class to the DbContext, and neither what to put in the `type` part of the config method. [Another example I found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) seemed to suggest that you write the namespace of a logger:

```
type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework"
```

I noted that [`DataBaseLogger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.databaselogger%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) implements `IDisposable`, `IDbConfigurationInterceptor` and
    [`IDbInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx). `IDbCommandInterceptor` also implements `IDbInterceptor`, so I tried (without success) to format it like this:

```
type="DataLayer.Logging.MyCommandInterceptor, DataLayer"
```

And when I called the static `DbInterception` class directly, it added another interceptor every call. So my quick and dirty solution was to utilize static constructors:

```
//This partial class is a seperate file from the Entity Framework auto-generated class,
//to allow dynamic connection strings
public partial class MyDbContext // : DbContext
{
    public Guid RequestGUID { get; private set; }

    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        DbContextListeningInitializer.EnsureListenersAdded();

        RequestGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
        //Database.Log = m => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(m);
    }

    private static class DbContextListeningInitializer
    {
        static DbContextListeningInitializer() //Threadsafe
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new MyCommandInterceptor());
        }
        //When this method is called, the static ctor is called the first time only
        internal static void EnsureListenersAdded() { }
    }
}
```

But what are the proper/intended ways to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out that my `DbContext` class just needed to have the `DbConfigurationType` attribute, to attach a configuration at runtime:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDBConfiguration))]
public partial class MyDbContext // : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    { }
}

public class MyDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration {
    public MyDBConfiguration() {
        this.AddInterceptor(new MyCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is thread-safe.  What happens if another thread has MyDBConfiguration2 and a similar constructor body?  Then both DbContext's will have MyCommandInterceptor registered twice, right?

Comment: In your `MyDBConfiguration` constructor, you dont have to use that static class, you have `this.AddInterceptor()` method.

Comment: @JohnZabroski Do you mean that DbInterception.Add() isn't thread-safe? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbinterception.add(v=vs.113).aspx) doesn't say so, so I'd assume you're right. Jan'splite'K.'s suggestion looks like the logical answer - and I tested it to confirm that it works. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Thread-safe may have been a poor/lazy choice of words. Really, the behavior of your code was not idempotent.

Comment: I agree with @JohnZabroski, I have two Contexts in different parts of the application and I had errors depending on which context was created first - the second complained that the DbConfigurationType was not the same, so all of this config is global

Comment: The documentation says that `DbConfiguration` is applied at the App-Domain level. It also says that `DbConfigurationType` attribute should be used when your `DbContext` is in a separate assembly from your configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) suggests that you can just put it in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    DbInterception.Add(new SchoolInterceptorTransientErrors());
    DbInterception.Add(new SchoolInterceptorLogging());
}
```

The important part is that it only gets called once.